# Transpose a matrix via pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I'm trying to transpose a matrix in C while passing the matrix to a function and return a pointer to a transposed matrix. What am I doing wrong in the second while loop?

in main

```
ptr = (float *) getMatrix(numRowsB, numColsB);
transposePtr = transpose(ptr, numRowsB, numColsB);
printf("\nBtranspose =\n");
printMatrix(transposePtr, numColsB, numRowsB);
```

create matrix

```
float* getMatrix(int n, int m)
{
  int i, j;
  float *arrayPtr;

  if ((n <= 0) || (m <= 0))
  {
    printf("function getMatrix(): matrix dimensions are invalid\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  arrayPtr = (float *) malloc(n*m*sizeof(float));
  if(arrayPtr == NULL)
  {
    printf("function getMatrix: Unable to malloc array\n");
    return NULL;
  }
```

transpose function

```
float* transpose(float *matrix, int n, int m)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    float num;
    float *transposed=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n*m);
        while(i < n-1)
        {
            while(j < m-1)
            {
                num = *(matrix+i*m+j);
                *(transposed+j*m+i)= num;
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }

    return transposed;
}
```

print fucntion

```
 void print(float *matrix, int n, int m)
{
   int i = 0;//row counter
   int j = 0;//col counter
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
     printf("\n");
     for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
       printf("%f ", *(matrix + i*n + j));
     }
   }
}
```

Example input:

```
1  2  3

4  5  6
```

Output:

```
 1.000000 0.000000

 2.000000 3396.580087

-0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: I believe I have answered your question.  There was a problem in my original posted and I updated my answer.  If an answer does not solve your problem, leaving a comment is generally better than removing your question text.

Comment: If you want to delete your question, please ask the posters who put quite some effort in their answers to delete their answers, then delete your question. But do not just delete all text, as that leaves the answers without context. Or leave a comment here that you did not find what you are looking for. Note that 1..2 hours is quite a short time to give up.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem was your print function

Here is a version of your functions that works:

```
float* transpose(float *matrix, int n, int m)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  float num;
  float *transposed=malloc(sizeof(float)*n*m);
  while(i < n) {
    j = 0;
    while(j < m) {
      num = *(matrix + i*m + j);
      *(transposed + i+n*j) = num; // I changed how you index the transpose
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return transposed;
}


void print(float *matrix, int n, int m)
{
  int i = 0;//row counter
  int j = 0;//col counter
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("\n");
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
      printf("%f ", *(matrix + i*m + j)); // Changed from n to m
    }
  }
}
```

There were a few things.

1. Use `sizeof(float)` instead of `sizeof(int)`
2. Your loop should be `i < n` and `j < m` instead of `i < n-1` and `j < m-1` and finally you need to reset `j` to zero every time
3. The matrix indexes in inner most loop of your transpose function was incorrect
4. Your print function was using the wrong variable in the multiplication

Also it is generally considered [bad practice to cast the result of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).